# Avoiding quotes in yaml field value

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a yaml file with content

```
ip:
  modules:
    shutdown-manager:
      version: 0.5
      package:
        repo: github
        path: ~/path
        manager: no
```

This is my program

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

with open('manifest.yml') as stream:
   documents = yaml.load(stream)
   en=(documents['ip']['modules']['shutdown-manager'])
   en.insert(1, 'enabled', 'false')
   print(en)


with open('manifest_new.yml', 'wb') as stream:
    yaml.dump(documents, stream)
```

This is the ouput i get

```
ip:
  modules:
    shutdown-manager:
      version: 0.5
      enabled: 'false'
      package:
        repo: github
        path: ~/path
        manager: no
```

In the content of new yaml you can see there is quotes coming in **enabled: 'false'**.
I want to avoid that quotes and the output should look like

```
ip:
  modules:
    shutdown-manager:
      version: 0.5
      enabled: false
      package:
        repo: github
        path: ~/path
        manager: no
```

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly setting the value of the `enabled` key to the *string* `false`, so `yaml.dump` produces a YAML string. Set it to the Boolean value `False` instead to get a YAML boolean.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get what you expect using `ruamel.yaml`, it is a good practise to load what you expect, see if that dumps back to what you expect without change, and then inspect that was what loaded.

You'll see that the expected YAML dumps back unchanged (especially not without quotes around `false`), and that `documents['ip']['modules']['shutdown-manager']['enabled']` equals the boolean value `False`. So you should insert that instead of the string `'false'`.

Also note that you load only one document with `.load()`, if you potentially have a multidocument stream, use `.load_all()`. And the recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since Sept. 2006.